# bat file to change date time of files in a folder with today date time reading the file name from a text list

Tags: file, date, batch-file, time, updates

I have a folder with a large number of files, these file will be periodically deleted using date time (old will be removed automatically).

I need to keep some files inside this folder and prevent them from being deleted automatically updating the date time of file.

The names of files to keep updating the date time are saved in a text file that contains only the file name to keep updating the date time of files.

My OS is Windows 7 32 bit language Italian

I add an example:

folder that contains all files:

```
log1.txt modified date lunedì ‎1 ‎gennaio ‎2019, ‏‎00:00:00
log2.txt modified date lunedì ‎1 ‎gennaio ‎2019, ‏‎00:03:00
log3.txt modified date lunedì ‎1 ‎gennaio ‎2019, ‏‎00:06:00
log6.txt modified date lunedì ‎1 ‎gennaio ‎2019, ‏‎00:08:00
log7.txt modified date lunedì ‎1 ‎gennaio ‎2019, ‏‎00:30:00
log9.txt modified date lunedì ‎1 ‎gennaio ‎2019, ‏‎00:40:00
log152.txt modified date lunedì ‎1 ‎gennaio ‎2019, ‏‎01:10:00
```

Content of list.txt with the files name to update modified date time:

```
log7.txt
log152.txt
log555.txt
log785.txt
log10150.txt
```

In this case after run the bat file these files need date time to update at today/now date time

```
log7.txt modified date venerdì ‎4 ‎ottobre ‎2019, ‏‎16:00:00 (today)
log152.txt modified date venerdì ‎4 ‎ottobre ‎2019, ‏‎16:00:00 (today)
```

All others files should not be changed when not included in the list of files to be updated.

The folder that contains the file to update have spaces in path.

The list of files to update is saved in different folder.

This is the code i tried it copy the files in the same folder to update the date time but i need to update only files names saved in text list.

```
cd C:\Users\Windows\Desktop\test
copy C:\Users\Windows\Desktop\test,,+
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free code writing, or personal assistant service. Here we help you to fix a specific issue with your provided code, given a [mcve] of that code, a full explanation of what happens when you run it, and what you've tried yourself in fixing it before requesting our assistance.

Comment: @Compo I add the code i use to update the date time of file (copy the file in same path) but i need to update only file name saved in test list. thanks for help.

Comment: Start  with `for /f "delims=" %%a in (list.txt) do echo %%a` - from there it should be easy...

Comment: @Stephan Thanks, i tried but the problem are the path with space, i posted a partial code but do not work with path with space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the complete and working solution.

These are my path:

> ```
> Path folder: D:\Programmi Installati\MyFolder
> Path list: D:\Programmi Installati\list.txt
> ```

```
@echo off
pushd "D:\Programmi Installati\MyFolder\"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%G in ('type "D:\Programmi Installati\list.txt"') do (
  copy "%%G",,+
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To process paths/filenames with spaces, you have to quote them like

```
"D:\Programmi Installati\list.txt"
```

to tell the parser that it's a single entity.

Unfortunately, the `for` syntax interprets a quoted string as a string, not as a filename, so this

```
for /f %%a in ("D:\Programmi Installati\list.txt") do ...
```

doesn't work (well - it does, but it won't process the contents of the file, but the literal string `D:\Programmi Installati\list.txt`). To actually process the contents of the file, you need to tell `for` to intepret quotes different:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("D:\Programmi Installati\list.txt") do ...
```

Where `usebackq` changes the way, quoting between the parentheses is interpreted, and `delims=` tells it to not delimit the line(s) (just in case there are spaces inside the file, like `log 777.txt`).